# Toggle script problems how can I fix this in pure JavaScript? No jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have made this script and I design it in a way when you click any where outside of the div the div should disappear but I notice that when you click on the div it self it disappear as well. How can I prevent that from occurring I only want it to work by clicking any where out side the div to make the div disappear 
not by clicking on the div to make it disappear as well. So i'm trying to prevent that. How can I do that? And I still want the toggle affect on the button as well.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var bx = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  bx.addEventListener('click', fx);

  function fx() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>

<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <img src='http://full.creative.touchtalent.com/The-enchanted-forest-97329.jpg'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `window.onclick` handler only checks to see if you clicked the button, not inside the `<div>`. Include the `<div>` check in your condition:

```
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !event.target.closest('.dropdown-content')) {
```

[`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) returns `null` if the element does not match and is not a descendant of an element that matches its argument.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now how I want it to work :)